# Set different variables to the same Variable result [Discord.py, Google Sheet API]

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api, discord.py

What i am trying to do it's ***cell_find*** to look for specific member's logged bans in my Google sheet API and after that, It'll display it in an Discord Embed, but the **problem** basically is when the bot send the embed it only shows one result instead of the 3 ones that should display

```
cell_find = sheet.findall('Banned')
var = 0
for cell in cell_find:
    var += 1
    sheet_username = sheet.cell(cell.row,3).value   
    sheet_reason = sheet.cell(cell.row,7).value
    if var == 4:
        break
```

The embed i'd like to try would be something like

```
embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{sheet_username}'s Incidents')
embed.addfield(name="Incident#1", value=f'{sheet_reason}')
embed.addfield(name="Incident#2", value=f'{sheet_reason}')
embed.addfield(name="Incident#3", value=f'{sheet_reason}')
await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try iterating over it in a for loop:

```py
sheet_username = sheet.cell(cell.row,3).value  
embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{sheet_username}'s Incidents")

for count, cell in enumerate(cell_find, 1): 
    sheet_reason = sheet.cell(cell.row,7).value
    embed.add_field(name=f"Incident#{count}", value=f"{sheet_reason}")

await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Without knowing how your google sheet is laid out, I'm not able to help on the columns, but you could use the `count` variable to add to the column perhaps? Something like `3 + count`?

But I think as far as logic goes, this is the way to go about adding fields.

---

**References:**

- [Enumerating in Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate)

Comment: Thank you very much Diggy, it worked ♥
Btw, do you know how to make it print only the second result, like ignore the first incident and print the second?

Comment: If you don't want to use hard-coded values, you can add an argument to the command which will let the user see specific incidents (and you can replace `1` in `enumerate()` with the argument).